# Normal to have API error while saving a Case Type?

Tags: civicase

I'm on CiviCRM 4.6.18 and Drupal. When I save a case type, I keep getting an error on the top right that says "API error: DB Error: already exists." I'm not sure if this is causing another issue I'm having which is when I create a case, the loading keeps hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was going on, but thank you to Eileen. I did the following steps on CiviCRM 4.7.18, probably not ideal if you already have data though.

1. Delete all cases and case types.
2. Delete all relationships
3. Disable CiviCase
4. Clear Cache
5. Re-enable CiviCase

Answer (score 0):

No, not normal. And not, AFAIK a known error. In order to make sense of something like this devs usually need debugging information. There is error output in the log files in the ConfigAndLog directory - on drupal sites this will usually be in sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog